# Spectral decomposition of a non-diagonalizable matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quantum-mechanics

If a matrix is Square Normal matrix then the matrix can be decomposed as:

$\hat{A}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_i|\psi_i><\psi_i|$

where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix and $\psi_i$ corresponding eigenvectors.

Suppose the matrix A is **not diagonalizable, but is still square**. The Geometric multiplicity is strictly lesser than the Algebraic multiplicity.

What kind of decomposition can be obtained for such a matrix in terms of it's eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

(I am using the bra-ket notation of quantum mechanics in this question)

Comment: Look at the SVD.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Decompositions_based_on_eigenvalues_and_related_concepts
Most used are SVD (when we allow left and right orthogonal components differ) are Jordan (when we allow ones above diagonal).